# how to get the current values of the dropdown and textarea in foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to get the current value of the textarea and dropdown `leave_id`. I'm getting the current value of the applied leave id from second dropdown. How can I get the current value of the first dropdown and textarea?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.status').change(function() {
    // alert($('.leave_comments').val());    
    // alert($(this).prev('.leave_type').prop('id')); 

    var leave_type = $('.leave_comments').val();
    var leave_comments = $(this).prev('.leave_type').prop('id');
    var leave_id = $(this).prop('id');
    var status = $(this).val();

    console.log(1);
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>leave/status',
      data: {
        status: status,
        leave_id: leave_id
      },
      dataType: 'html', // return tyoe
      success: function(response) { // success response
        //$(response).appendTo('#success');
        $('#success').html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" \n\
data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' + response + '</div>');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<tbody>
  <?php $count=1 ?>
  <?php foreach ($leave as $leave): ?>
  <tr class="gradeX">
    <td>
      <?php echo $count++ ?>
    </td>
    <td id="name">
      <?php echo $leave->first_name . ' ' . $leave->last_name ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $leave->leave_applied_date ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $leave->name ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $leave->subject ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo date( 'd/m/Y', strtotime($leave->leave_from_date)) . ' - ' . date('d/m/Y', strtotime($leave->leave_to_date)) ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $leave->reason ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php if($leave->leave_comments == null) { ?>
      <textarea class="form-control leave_comments" rows="5" placeholder="Type your answer..." required="required"></textarea>
      <?php } else { ?>
        <?php echo $leave->leave_comments ?>
      <?php } ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="leave_id" class="form-control input-md mb-md leave_type" id="<?php echo $leave->applied_leave_id ?>">
        <option value="">Select leave type</option>
        <?php foreach($leave_types as $type): ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $type->leave_id ?>">
          <?php echo $type->name ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
    </td>
    <!--   <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_edit" onclick="modal_edit('<?php echo base_url() . 'leave/leave_reason/' . $leave->leave_id . '/' . $leave->employee_id ?>')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit" class="btn-sm btn-warning"  href=""><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>-->
    <td>
      <select id="<?php echo $leave->applied_leave_id ?>" class="status" data-plugin-selectTwo class="form-control populate placeholder">
        <option value="">
          <?php echo $leave->status ? $leave->status : 'Pending' ?>
        </option>
        <option value="Granted">Granted</option>
        <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
var textarea = $(this).closest('.gradeX').find('.leave_comments').val();
var first_select =$(this).closest('.gradeX').find('input[name="leave_id"]').val();
```

Comment: dear brother please be more specific, what exactly isn't working?